# Using input character as argument in formula in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use a user supplied text input (site number) in Shiny to retrieve data through the USGS dataRetrieval package.  The formula `dataRetrieval::readNWISpeak()` requires site numbers to be entered as quoted text.  But I cannot get it to work using the reactive variable.

minimum working example

```
library(dataRetrieval)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
      div(
            textInput("site",
                      "Enter Site Code",
                      value = "12448500")
      ),
      div(
            verbatimTextOutput("site.out"),
            tableOutput("returns")
      )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
      output$site.out <- renderText(as.character(input$site))
      parameterCd <- "00060" # Discharge
      # #     Works
      peak_flows = readNWISpeak(siteNumbers = "12448500")

      # #    This runs into problems
      # siteNumber <- reactive({
      #       site <- input$site
      # })
      # peak_flows = readNWISpeak(siteNumbers = siteNumber)

      output$returns <- renderTable(head(peak_flows))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Trying to force the it as a string and replacing the working line above:

```
peak_flows = readNWISpeak(enquote(reactive({input$site})))
>
>  Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7633
>  Request failed [400]. Retrying in 1.2 seconds...                                                                                          
>  Request failed [400]. Retrying in 2.2 seconds...
>  HTTP Status 400 - no key-value pairs supplied by user
>  Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected
>    46: stop
>    45: [.data.frame
>    41: readNWISpeak
>    40: server [#10]
>     3: runApp
>     2: print.shiny.appobj
>     1: <Anonymous>
>  Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c("agency_cd", "site_no")) : 
>    undefined columns selected
```

I've tried other configurations (e.g. `as.character()`, with and without `reactive({})`, ...) but the window shows up and immediately disappears with a cannot coerce into character vector or similar error message.

Comment: Define `peak_flows` as reactive: `peak_flows = reactive(readNWISpeak(siteNumbers = input$site))` then use `()` to get the current value of the reactive value `output$returns <- renderTable(head(peak_flows()))`. This is really basic shiny stuff. If you are new to shiny, check out the talks by Joe Cheng on reactivity: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/